# How to use currency formatting at i18n + Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-i18n

I have `{{n (100, "currency")}}` and I would like to display it as $100 - but how can I get n correctly? For example when I'm using

```
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";
```

```html
 setup() {
    const { t, n } = useI18n({
      locale: "en-US",

      numberFormats: {
        "en-US": {
          currency: {
            style: "currency",
            currency: "USD",
          },
        },
      },
    });

    return { t, n };
  },
```

I get an error `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Invalid arguments` How can I solve this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. VueI18n must be [initialized](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/#javascript) 1st by using `createI18n` and `app.use()`
2. To use composition API, the `legacy: false` [must be used](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/composition.html#basic-usage)

See example below. Note that `VueI18n.createI18n` or `Vue.createApp` in the example is used because scripts are loaded from CDN. When used with bundler, just use `import` and use `createApp` or `createI18n` directly...

```js
const i18n = VueI18n.createI18n({
  legacy: false,
  locale: "en-US",
  numberFormats: {
    "en-US": {
      currency: {
        style: "currency",
        currency: "USD",
      },
    },
  },
})

const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const { n } = VueI18n.useI18n()
    return { n }
  }
})
app.use(i18n)
app.mount("#app")
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-i18n@next"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ n(100, "currency") }}
</div>
```

Comment: You could add `globalInjection: true,` entry to the i18n config  next to `legacy: false,` which makes `$n` available globally then use it like `{{ $n(100, "currency") }}` without using  `useI18n`

Comment: Or you could use `legacy: true` (which is default), use global i18n instance with `import` and avoid using `useI18n()` in every component. But the OP's example was using Composition API so I used it too in my answer...

Comment: Thanks, it works, but can I put "numberFormats" for example in the tag <i18n> so as not to litter i18n.js

Comment: @Gorilka I really doubt it. From the [docs](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/sfc.html#single-file-components) it seems `<i18n>` custom block are intended only for messages. On the other hand defining number/date formats globally instead in a SFC feels as a right approach...